# Create runbook to execute bash script

Tags: linux, bash, azure, webhooks, runbook

I have a .sh file stored on my azure Linux VM. I want to create a webhook that executes this script. I found that I first need to create a runbook for this. Until now I tried to create a powershell runbook and tried to execute my .sh file with 'Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand'. It says that it doesn't recognize the term Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand.

Do you have any idea how I can solve this?

Cheers!

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: @Siem Peters Is there is any update from your side about the answer below ?

Answer (score 0):

About the Error

> doesn't recognize the term `Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand`

Which comes if you don't install the `AzureRm.Compute` module in *Azure Automation*

You could install any modules by referring this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-gallery#modules-in-powershell-gallery)